# why auto increment id is used as primary key  in DATA dictionary even though already  primary key is available in ER diagram?

Tags: database, database-design

HERE,i have seen ER diagram that there is no auto increment id key is available but in data dictionary i saw id .In er diagram which attribute is used as primary key is used as unique key in data dictionary and   auto increment id is used as primary key which one is not in the ER diagram.why this happen?

```
field    KEY              other                     NULL?

id      Primary key      auto increment             Not null

Name    Unique key                                  Not Null
....     ...........                                 ...........
```

Can any one say why primary key id is used without showing it in the ER diagram?and why ER diagram's primary key is used as UNIQUE key in the data dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in principle between a primary key and any other key. All keys are supposed to be irreducibly unique and non-nullable whether you choose to designate them as a "primary" one or not. So designating any one primary key when you have several possible candidate keys is a somewhat flexible, informal concept that is only as important as the designer wants it to be. Perhaps the difference you are seeing just reflects different opinions or intended uses. Of course another possibility is that someone made a simple mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The use of I'd might be for consistency; some frameworks assume that every table has id as the primary key, which standardizes/simplifies working with tables.  But the "real" primary key from the ER diagram would be a valid key, so why not inform the DB off this by flagging it as UNIQUE?

Comment: how it  maintain consistency by adding auto increment primary key which one is not showing in ER diagram?there is also change that ER diagram's primary key is used as Unique key in DATA dictionary.

Comment: Consistency in how all tables are handled.  If EVERY table uses ID as the primary key, then the same code can be used to identify records no matter what table.

Answer (score 0):

One possiblity ID is a surrogate key, NAME is natural one, there are a number of advantages to a design using surrogate keys. For instance they are (well should be) immutable.

If there's another table linked by ID, you could change name (e.g. fix a spilling mestike) without breaking referential integrity, or havng to rekey the dependant tables.

Another would be you didn't want Name to be unique anymore, perhaps add another column for context, and make Name and Context a compound unique key, imagine how painful it would be to rework all the related tables.

Rule 1 of surrogates though, don't expose them.

Comment: but in surrogate key id is auto increment primary key and name is not unique key but in our case name is unique and every time it is validated for checking duplication.so,i think in our case id-name is not surrogate key.are u sure  it is surrogate key?

Comment: Surrogate keys are used to make your design more flexible, ie if name became not unique in some future enhancement, you wouldn't be looking at a huge amount of work in your design to accomplish it. A purist would say never use a natural key as a foreign key.